# How to process HTML on server before sending

Tags: php, html, apache2, server-side

I want to run a script to process the HTML of a web page just before output - after all PHP and other server side scripts have finished running - adding meta and doing other subtle changes. This is on linux with apache server. Is there a standard way to do this?

I have read about output filters in `apache`. Is this the right way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Isnt that what allllllllllllllllllllll the web programing server-side languages  already do? Isnt that how web works in the first place? Isnt that what apache server does already

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - thank you,  Mr. Panky, for your constructive and helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):
you can tell php to start buffering your output using `ob_start();` then after you finish buffering your content you can send it to the browser as a whole using `ob_end_flush();`, an example:

```
<?php
// start output buffering at the top of our script with this simple command
ob_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
<?php echo "<p>Hello again!</p>"; ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// end output buffering and send our HTML to the browser as a whole
ob_end_flush();
?>
```